# Test Errors are not caught when using ParallelComputer Junit.

Tags: java, junit

I have long running tests. So, I started using ParallelComputer feature of JUnit.

here is the sample code

```
Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(ParallelComputer.class, new Class[]{Class1.class, Class2.class});
```

One of my test case was throwing error. But, it was not getting captured by `result.getFailures()`. Is there any way to propagate errors  to the caller?

Comment: This: `Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(ParallelComputer.classes(), new Class[] {TestOne.class, TestTwo.class}); for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()) { ... }` **is** the prescribed way of propagating test failures (or any exceptions from test cases) encountered in a `ParallelComputer` invocation. So, if it's not working for you then something other than what you have posted in your question is going wrong. Please update your question to include `Class1`, `Class2` and the entire method from which you call `JUnitCore.runClasses()`.

Comment: Failures are getting propogated but not errors. In case of any errors or exceptions, junit doesn't treat them as failure. For example if NullPointerException, I can't figure out the stack trace

Comment: Again, `org.junit.runner.Result.failures` is the prescribed way of propagating exceptions (JUnit AssertionError or NullPointerException or any subclass of `Exception` or `Error`) back to the caller so if you are not seeing exceptions propagated in this way then something other than what you have posted in your question is going wrong. If you want help diagnosing this then providing a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is the best way of enabling others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check number of failures in `Result`, then assert that it equals zero , if the assertion fails (means that some test cases failed) then method fails also, check code below :

```
Class[] cls = {XXXTestCase.class};
Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(XXXTestCase.methods(), cls);
assertThat("Failing test cases should be Zero", result.getFailureCount(), equalTo(0));
```